# How to initiate TLSv1.2 request in jre6

Tags: java, tls1.2

How to initiate a TLSv1.2 request from jre6 using JAVA. The URL that I am using is of TLSv1.2 but my application uses only jre6. If a request is sent from jre6 we get NoSuchAlgorithmFound exception and how to solve this.  Can any one please help how to initiate a TLSv1.2 request in JAVA so that no such exceptions arises.

Comment: Have tried the same code we got NoSuchAlgorithmFound Exception. If the code is correct kindly request you to be specific about both jars as well as Java Code

Comment: Kindly provide full code snippet

Comment: If possible kindly provide the complete code Snippet.